# In Android, how to process bytes from bluetooth and write them to CSV file?

Tags: android, csv, bluetooth

I'm writing an android app that essentially creates a CSV file from data received over bluetooth. The data received needs to be processed and formatted for CSV. What's the best way to go about this? I'm a novice java programmer, but I'm thinking of using this approach. One thread reads input from bluetooth and validates the packet is good. If the packet is good, another thread or asynctask or service (not sure which to use, any suggestions?) will process the data, format it, then write it to a SQLite database. Once both the read thread and process thread are finished, I write everything in the database to a CSV file. I'm not very familiar with multithreading or services, so any example code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google for what you want if face any problem then post here.

Comment: I have been looking but I've never used services or asynctasks. So I'm wondering if either would be a better option than threads.

Comment: There is no magic that can solve your problems so you have to learn these things :).

Comment: I'm not looking for magic, I am trying to learn the differences and best use of multithreading, asynctasks, and services.